# MongoDB Query performance related to Chunks

Tags: mongodb, io, query-optimization, chunks

I want to understand if there is an impact on query performance depending on how the data is stored in Chunks.

Let's make an example:

1. Case
   Names are stored in an ascending order and depending on the ranges moved to different chunks

```
Achmed --> Chunk 1
George --> Chunk 2
Henry  --> Chunk 2
Paul   --> Chunk 3
```

2. Case
   the Names are stored as a hashed value and therefore the data is distributed differently to the shard. The hash values are just examples to keep the example easy

```
Achmed (hashvalue 8)  --> Chunk 3
George (hashvalue 2)  --> Chunk 1
Henry  (hashvalue 9)  --> Chunk 3
Paul   (hashvalue 7)  --> Chunk 3
```

My question is now, when I query for Names George and Henry, will the performance be the same or will it be better in case 1 because both names are stored in the same chunk and I need maybe less I/O?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Here you are referring to chunks in a sharded cluster? Where (which shards) do the chunks reside on in your two examples?

Comment: @user20042973  you are right. Let me rephrase my question and remove the sharded cluster topic.